# Android Buttons will not change my active layout

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-emulator

My buttons make no motion or color change (are they supposed to?) They also do not do as directed (I've only coded for one) I intend for them to change the active layout, but they are not doing so. Below is the code pertaining to the issue. Thanks!

So here is my java code for the click listener:

```
Button lost = (Button)findViewById(R.id.lost1);
        lost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent("com.guruguru2.lostnfound.FOUNDTEXT"));
                System.out.println("pressed");
            }
        });
```

and the manifest referencing that intent:

```
<activity
            android:name=".FoundText"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.guruguru2.lostnfound.FOUNDTEXT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And finally, the Layout with the button's XML (only the pertaining sections):

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/lost1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/lost"
        android:textColor="@color/lostfoundtext"
        android:textColorLink="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_headline_material"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/found1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Found"
         android:textColor="@color/lostfoundtext"
        android:textColorLink="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_headline_material"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:typeface="serif" />
```

Comment: What are you using the intent for?

Answer (score 0):

Open your activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.guruguru2.lostnfound.FOUNDTEXT");
startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, FoundText.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I changed it just to be sure, but still no change in activity or animation on the button.

Comment: @alashowSo the button IS WORKING but there is a) Extreme lag of about 6 seconds before it starts the next activity and b) when the next activity is started, the screen goes black and the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code with a new project and it worked just fine. When I clicked the Lost button it switched to the new activity. The button click animation also played. I suspect there might be something going on with your layout if the button is not playing animations and not doing what you expect.

Can you verify the button handler is getting called? Try putting a System.out.println() inside the handler or use the debugger and set a breakpoint.

P.S.:
It won't hurt anything, but I do know you don't need this line in the manifest, inside Activity:

```
<action android:name="com.guruguru2.lostnfound.FOUNDTEXT" />
```

Launching an activity only requires the full name of the activity; your activity does not need to handle the intent.

Comment: So when it is clicked. nothing is being outputted into the console. I added a small line instructing it to do so :/ So the handler is not getting called.

Comment: So the button IS WORKING but there is a) Extreme lag of about 6 seconds before it starts the next activity and b) when the next activity is started, the screen goes black and the app crashes.

Comment: What is the stack trace when it crashes?

Comment: I don't have any experience with the DeadObjectException.